# Bootstrap Dropdown not working ASP .NET

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm tearing my hair out now. Hope you guys can help. I'm trying to create a drop down menu. No idea why it is'nt working. Code is below. Any ideas?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Find Property</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">Property For Sale</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Property For Rent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Launches</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Commercial Property</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Find Rooms/Flatmate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_dropdowns.asp

Comment: And http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: Yes. Thank you v much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out, the below links to make sure your using the right classes and markup.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_dropdowns.asp

And http://getbootstrap.com/components/